# Angular 14: Upload images

Tags: angular

I need to add a feature to upload and retrieve images in angular v14. I checked in Google i could not find any solution working in Angular 14,i got solution for older Angular versions.

Comment: The current version of Angular is 12.2.6 and the next tag is 13.0.0-next.6, so what do you mean by Angular 14?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yah we are still on Angular 12, maybe search for solutions on Angular 12 and you'll find plenty of them. Maybe you mean't your Node Js version? Still wouldn't make much of a difference...